# How to set HTTP request using AFNetworking 2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, request, afnetworking-2

I need to send ordinary HTTP request (GET) and answer will in text/html.
How can I send this response using AFNetworkin 2 ?

Now I'm trying to use

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com"]];
[self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                  NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
                              } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                              }];
```

And was frustrates - it do nothing. When debugging, nor success nor fail clause have been triggered.

Also I tried to use GET:parameters:success:failure:  method, but in response I see this error:

> Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request
>   failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"

Please, anybody can explain me what are wrong and what is the correct way to send request (if I will get response  as text/html)?

Regards, Alex.

Comment: Have you tried using http instead of https?

Comment: I need https. But I think it doesn't matter

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You said in your comment, in response to the suggestion to use the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`:

> When I used GET I got this error as I wrote above: Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"

You can remedy that with a `AFHTTPResponseSerializer`:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:@"https://example.com" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // do whatever you'd like here; for example, if you want to convert 
    // it to a string and log it, you might do something like:

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

You can also use `AFHTTPRequestOperation`:

```
NSOperationQueue *networkQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
networkQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // do whatever you'd like here; for example, if you want to convert 
    // it to a string and log it, you might do something like:

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%s: AFHTTPRequestOperation error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
}];
[networkQueue addOperation:operation];
```

Ideally, though, it's advisable to write server code that returns JSON (or XML), as that's much easier for an app to consume and parse.

Comment: is it the way AFNetworking encourages us to use? The first segment of code is simple but I can't find AFNetworking is teaching this. :(. I just doubt why AFNetworking is not teaching me to use it to send a simple GET request

Comment: Yes, setting the `responseSerializer` to match the format of the expected response is the recommended way. The reason AFNetworking is not teaching you to use `ATHTTPResponseSerializer` because you shouldn't generally write a web service that returns JSON response with a `Content-Type` of `text/html`! In LIAL's question, he clearly indicates that he's expecting JSON response, but his web service's response is failing to set the `Content-Type` header appropriately. If a web service is returning JSON, it should set its headers accordingly (e.g. in PHP, `header("Content-Type: application/json")`).

Comment: Notice, though, that this answer is written for AFNetworking 2.x. In later versions, you would use neither `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` nor `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. But the setting of `responseSerializer` works the same way in `AFHTTPSessionManager`. But, as I said, if the web service set its response's headers appropriately for the JSON response payload, you wouldn't have to mess with `responseSerializer` at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
//AFN 2.0 is just support IOS 7,and it's standard use as follow:

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" 
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
               NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject)
     }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
               NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }
];
```

Comment: When I used GET I got this error as I wrote above:   Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"

Comment: @LIAL Add `manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];` to let it know that you'll accept `text/html` response.

Comment: Yep, been already done. Just have to convert row data I got to readable string.